# Azure AD guest user multi factor authentication

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, openid-connect, multi-factor-authentication

I manage my Azure Active Directory - MyProjectAAD.
I've added external users as guest from another Azure Active Directory - MyCompanyAAD

When user@MyCompanyAAD.com wants to login to app, that is registered in **MyCompanyAAD**, two factor authentication is enforced. *Note: User is redirected to custom Enterprise Sign On Page and custom second authentication page*

However, when the same users wants to login to app, that is registered in **MyProjectAAD** where he is guest, two factor authentication is not enforced and I want to enfornce it. *User is only redirected to the same custom Enterprise Sign on as in previous case, but no second factor authentication page*

**How do I enable two factor authentication for guest users in my Azure Active Directory?**

Answer (score 0):

You can use Azure Conditional access to achieve that.

*NOTE: This feature needs AAD Premium to create your own policies for your scenario.*

> **1. Create a Dynamic Access Group of "External User" accounts**
>
> - Login to AzureAD Portal, and navigate to Azure Active Directory -> Users and Groups -> All groups and click on New Group
> - Give your group a friendly name, description, and select Membership type of Dynamic User.  If you do not see this Membership type, it may
>     be that you do not have AzureAD Premium licenses in your subscription.
>     (See licensing requirements below)
> - Select Add dynamic query, and create a Simple Rule in which you add users where  userType Equals Guest
> - Click Add query -> Create in order to make the dynamic group
>
> *NOTE: It will take some time for the group to populate.*
>
> **2. Create a Conditional Access Policy for the specific Enterprise App.**
>
> - Login to AzureAD Portal, and navigate to Enterprise applications >Select the specific app> Conditional access to show all Conditional access policies, and then click on New Policy
> - On the New blade, in the name text box, type a friendly name for the policy
> - On the Users and Groups blade, select Include -> Select users and group -> Select
> - Search for the External Users group you created in the previous step and select that group
> - On the Conditions blade, select Locations.  Select Yes for Configure.  Include Any Location.
> - Apply these by selecting the Done buttons
> - On the Grant Blade, select Grant Access and Require Multi-Factor Authentication.  Click Select to apply the Grant restrictions.
>     -Finally, toggle the Enable policy button to On, and then Create the policy

Here is [a blog](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/kekirkpa/2017/10/13/enforcing-multi-factor-authentication-for-external-users-on-sharepoint-online/) is written by Kevin Kirkpatrick, You can refer to it to enforce Multi-Factor Authentication for External Users on a specific app.

Comment: MyCompany AAD from where I'm adding users already has AAD Premium and Multifactor authentication enabled. Isn't it possible to enforce multifactor authentication even when logging in as a guest in another AAD? Notice that I don't want to create my own multifactor authentication, but I need to reuse the exiting one